# Unable to change header height in HTML

Tags: html, css, email, header

I have created a header for our companies email templates, luckily I was able to find a basic template on the web and tweak it to our requirements.
I am a real beginner when it comes to HTML so I am sure there are many errors in it too. 
I need to figure out how to reduce the blue banner to 42px in height but everything I try ruins it. I have also been told that my 600 wide option is very old school and it should be 1200. I have tried to change this too, but then it loses all of the other formatting and looks terrible.
Its supposed to be responsive, if anyone could make any edit suggestions I would be very grateful.

[header.txt](http://hosted.hayley-group.co.uk/misc/stack/header.txt)
[header.html](http://hosted.hayley-group.co.uk/misc/stack/header.html)

Comment: I would suggest that, rather than trying to hack an existing template that you don't understand, you take a little bit of time to get to grips with the basics of HTML/CSS and write your own.  
The example code you give is quite complex, mixing inline styles with a stylesheet, multiple table elements etc. so trying to modify this for your specific needs is going to cause you more work than it's worth.  
If you learn the basics of the box model & positioning you should be easily able to recreate what you need.

Comment: I totally agree @Sam that would be best in an ideal world but I have be thrown in at the deep end with a deadline to meet. Maybe one day when I am given the time I can try from scratch to create something but for now I have to try and work with what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the padding in the td containing the logo/image. To decrease the height of the blue banner, decrease the padiing at top and bottom of the above mentioned table data.

This helps you but another way is to decrease the logos height.

Comment: That worked a treat thank you! I changed the padding around the logo down to 1px and then the logo down to 40 and its reduced the size significantly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the codes, there is no specific "height" that is being assigned to the table containers that you can change to specify to 42px. The most that you can do is to remove the "top" and "bottom" padding from the containers inside to make the header's height smaller.

Here's a sample code with the changes. If you notice, I changed the top and bottom padding to 0px. For the second td, I left 5px for the top padding to add some spaces between the logos and the top edge of the screen. If you want to edit the width, I change the width to 800px but you also need to adjust the widths of the 2 containers inside the table. For example, I changed them from 270px to 370px each.

Lastly, I agree that this "template" that you found seems very complex and it would be better to learn a little bit of basic html and css and what you're trying to do is simple and can be done with much simpler codes. Good luck!

```
<center>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="800" class="w320">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" width="370" style="background:#2980B9;padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;">
              <a href="https://www.hayley-group.co.uk/" style="text-decoration:none;">
                <img src="http://hosted.hayley-group.co.uk/shop/hayley_web_logo_white(trans).png" width="110" height="auto" alt="Hayley Group PLC Logo"/>
              </a>
            </td>
            <td valign="top"  width="370" style="background:#2980B9;padding:5px 15px 0px 15px">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobile-center-block" align="right">
                <tr>
                  <td align="right">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/HayleyGroup/">
                    <img src="http://hosted.hayley-group.co.uk/shop/social_facebook.png"  width="30" height="30" alt="social icon"/>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td align="right" style="padding-left:5px">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/HayleyGroup">
                    <img src="http://hosted.hayley-group.co.uk/shop/social_twitter.png"  width="30" height="30" alt="social icon"/>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td align="right" style="padding-left:5px">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/hayley-group">
                    <img src="http://hosted.hayley-group.co.uk/shop/social_linkedin.png"  width="30" height="30" alt="social icon"/>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                 </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
 </center>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helpful and has helped me grasp a little better understanding of how padding and td's work. I'll give it a go. A combination of what you have suggested and what @uttejh said, should help me out massively! Next project, learn how to build a basic html page all by myself!